# How to make Python CUDA atomicAdd to work with long int

Tags: python, cuda

How can I make Python CUDA atomicAdd works with long int?  I tried with the below code, and it does not work as long as I use  `long *result_count`  or `atomicAdd(&InitianCount,1);`, with compilation error such as below.

```
import os

_path = r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx64\x64"

if os.system("cl.exe"):
    os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + _path
if os.system("cl.exe"):
    raise RuntimeError("cl.exe still not found, path probably incorrect")

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

InitianCount = 0

record_result = np.zeros((100000000, 4)).astype(np.float32) 
record_result_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(record_result.nbytes)

# result_count = np.int64(0)
result_count = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int64)
result_count_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(result_count.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(result_count_gpu, result_count)

print('result_count.nbytes is ' + str(result_count.nbytes))

mod = SourceModule("""
  #include <cstdlib>

  __global__ void test_cuda_LongIntArray(long InitianCount, int *result_count, float *record_result)
//  __global__ void test_cuda_LongIntArray(long InitianCount, long *result_count, float *record_result)
  {
      long result_index;
      result_index = atomicAdd(result_count,1);
//      result_index = atomicAdd(&InitianCount,1);
  }
  """)
      
func = mod.get_function("test_cuda_LongIntArray")
func( np.int64(InitianCount), result_count_gpu, record_result_gpu, block=(4,16,16))

record_result = np.empty((100000000, 4), dtype=np.float32)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(record_result, record_result_gpu)

print('record_result is with dimension ' + str(len(record_result)) + ' x ' + str(len(record_result[0])))
print(record_result)

record_result_gpu.free()
```

```
'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.33.31629 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

result_count.nbytes is 8
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\PythonProjects\TradeAnalysis\Test\TestCUDAUtilisationBrute_Long_a.py:34 in <module>
    mod = SourceModule("""

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycuda\compiler.py:352 in __init__
    cubin = compile(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycuda\compiler.py:301 in compile
    return compile_plain(source, options, keep, nvcc, cache_dir, target)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycuda\compiler.py:154 in compile_plain
    raise CompileError(

CompileError: nvcc compilation of C:\Users\henry\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjggfucw2\kernel.cu failed
```

Comment: You can find the supported data types in the [docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicadd). Maybe `unsigned long long` would be an option?

Comment: long has an inconsistent size across platforms. On Windows it is always the same size as int. On Linux/Mac/BSD it is the same size as int on 32 bit and the same as long long on 64 bit. I suggest you either switch to a consistent type or do some ```reinterpret_cast```s based on the ```sizeof(long)``` information

Answer (score 2):

First, on windows, `long` (or `long int`) [is a (signed) 32-bit (integer) type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-170).  So when asking for "how to use atomics with `long`" while at the same time allocating for 64-bit types in your code:

```
result_count = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int64)
```

begs the question are you really asking about how to use atomics with `long`, or are you really asking about how to use atomics on a 64-bit integer type?  I'll assume you want 64-bit atomics.  In CUDA, `atomicAdd` for 64-bit integer types is only supported for unsigned types.  So we will choose to use `unsigned long long` here, as it is unambiguously 64-bits unsigned on either windows or linux (for all currently supported CUDA activity using 64-bit OS's).

Second, to address your attempt in comments,  you cannot do atomics on a local variable.  When you use this variable:

```
__global__ void test_cuda_LongIntArray(long InitianCount,
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

in a thread, that is effectively thread-local.  Atomics work on global (or shared) variables.  A global variable will generally be passed to a kernel using a pointer, perhaps like so:

```
__global__ void test_cuda_LongIntArray(long *InitianCount,
```

If we aim for that (albeit using the `result_count` example), we can create something like this:

```
$ cat t36.py
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np

InitianCount = 0

record_result = np.zeros((10000000, 4)).astype(np.float32)
record_result_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(record_result.nbytes)

# result_count = np.int64(0)
result_count = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.uint64)
result_count_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(result_count.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(result_count_gpu, result_count)

print('result_count.nbytes is ' + str(result_count.nbytes))

mod = SourceModule("""
  #include <cstdlib>

  __global__ void test_cuda_LongIntArray(long long InitianCount, unsigned long long *result_count, float *record_result)
//  __global__ void test_cuda_LongIntArray(long InitianCount, long *result_count, float *record_result)
  {
      unsigned long long result_index;
      result_index = atomicAdd(result_count,1);
//      result_index = atomicAdd(&InitianCount,1);
  }
  """)

func = mod.get_function("test_cuda_LongIntArray")
func( np.int64(InitianCount), result_count_gpu, record_result_gpu, block=(4,16,16))

cuda.memcpy_dtoh(record_result, record_result_gpu)

print('record_result is with dimension ' + str(len(record_result)) + ' x ' + str(len(record_result[0])))
print(record_result)

record_result_gpu.free()
$ python t36.py
result_count.nbytes is 8
record_result is with dimension 10000000 x 4
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 ...,
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
$
```